# How to remove last couple of lines in the text file with powershell

Tags: powershell, file-get-contents, skip

**I have a text file as follows**

Apple=1

Manggo=1

Appleandmanggobellongsto=Jimmy

Apple=1

Manggo=1

Appleandmanggobellongsto=Dave

Apple=1

Manggo=1

Appleandmanggobellongsto=Carlton

**I want to remove the last 3 lines and this is what I want to achieve:**

Apple=1

Manggo=1

Appleandmanggobellongsto=Jimmy

Apple=1

Manggo=1

Appleandmanggobellongsto=Dave

$File = c:\Text.txt

get-content $File | select-object -skiplast 3 | set-contect $File

but I dont get anything.

please tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set-Contect` is not a built-in cmdlet, assuming you meant `Set-Content` then the issue is that you're trying to **read and write to the same file in a single pipeline** which results in a blank file. You need to consume the output from `Get-Content` first and then write to the file, for that you can use the [grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--)

```bash
$File = 'c:\Text.txt'
(Get-Content $File) | Select-Object -SkipLast 3 | Set-Content $File
```